# Should I commit misc.xml in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I recently start my Android development journey and found that there is a file called `misc.xml` in my project. I have read the [JetBrains' article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems) on how to manage a project in version control system. I have also walked through [Android.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Android.gitignore) file on a GitHub repository as well.

The article mentions we could commit `misc.xml` (because it is not in any exception) while Android.gitignore said we could omit the complete `.idea` folder and `misc.xml`.

So..

1. What do you think on this?
2. Is there any way I could get help from support to have an official answer?

**P.S.** I found that some absolute paths are being inject to `misc.xml`, and that frustrates me.

[image: Absolute path]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**misc.xml** is not associated with the app which you are making.
Thats  actually created by Android Studio itself to keep track of some paths.
You can ignore that using .gitignore.